# Why flutter return me my fallback values?

Tags: android, html, firebase, flutter, dart

so I've already have a problem with this code before I ask for some help and I got some.
The help fix my error but I have a new one .
So basically I'm waiting for a variable and this variable is not null because when I print it I can see the value of this variable.
The screen return me the fallback values and I don't know why.
I have two screens one for create my variable and the other for all the graphic stuff.

This is the detail screen:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DetailScreen({Key? key, required this.mangaImg, required this.mangaTitle, required this.mangalink}) : super(key: key);
  final String mangaImg,mangaTitle,mangalink;
  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
    String? mangaGenre,mangaStatus,mangaAuthor,mangaDesc;
  List<Map<String,dynamic>>? mangaDetail;
  List<Map<String,dynamic>>? mangaDescList;
  List<Map<String,dynamic>>? mangaChapters;

  Future<void> getMangaInfo() async {
    String  TempBaseurl = widget.mangalink.split(".com")[0] + ".com";
    String TempRoute = widget.mangalink.split(".com")[1];
    final webscraper = WebScraper(TempBaseurl);
    if (await webscraper.loadWebPage(TempRoute)){
     mangaDetail = webscraper.getElement("div.panel-story-info > div.story-info-right > table > tbody > tr > td.table-value", []);
     mangaDescList = webscraper.getElement("div.panel-story-info > div.panel-story-info-description", []);
   }

   mangaGenre  = mangaDetail![3]['title'].toString().trim();
   mangaStatus = mangaDetail![2]['title'].toString().trim();
   mangaAuthor = mangaDetail![1]['title'].toString().trim();
   mangaDesc   = mangaDescList![0]['title'].toString().trim();
   print(mangaDesc);
   print(mangaGenre);
   print(mangaStatus);

  }

    @override

    Future<void> getMangaInfos()async {
    await getMangaInfo();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screensize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Constants.mygreen,
        title: Text(widget.mangaTitle),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: screensize.height,
        width: screensize.width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MangaInfo(
                mangaImg: widget.mangaImg,
                mangaStatus: mangaStatus??"Error" ,
                mangaAuthor : mangaAuthor??"Error" ,
```

And this is the graphic screen:

```
class MangaInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  const MangaInfo({Key? key,  required this.mangaImg,    required this.mangaStatus,   required this.mangaAuthor}) : super(key: key);
  final String mangaImg, mangaStatus,mangaAuthor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      width: double.infinity,

      child: Column(

        children: [
          Expanded(child: Center(child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Container(height: 170, width: 130,child: Image.network(mangaImg, fit: BoxFit.cover,)
              ),
              Text("By $mangaAuthor - $mangaStatus"
                  , style: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "SFProDisplay",
              ))
            ],
          ))),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: const[
                MangaInfoBtn(icon:Icons.play_arrow, title: "Read"),
                MangaInfoBtn(icon:Icons.library_add_check, title: "Favorites"),
                MangaInfoBtn(icon:Icons.list, title: "Chapters"),]
```

An image of the screen for more details :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you get the manga information on the method called `getMangaInfo`, you await said method on the method `getMangaInfos` But you never call `getMangaInfos`! you also override it, but I don't think it is a method declared in `State` class. This leads me to believe that what you actually meant to do was this:

```
Future<void> initState() async {
  await getMangaInfo();
}
```

The above is **NOT POSSIBLE** and will result in a compilation error because `initstate` should never return a future. The next best thing is this:

```
void initState() {
  getMangaInfo();
}
```

But this means you are not awaiting `getMangaInfo`

Both `initState` and `build` methods are **synchronous**, which means you can't use the `await` keyword on them, on the other hand `getMangaInfo` is **asynchronous**. Asynchronous methods will be run whenever `flutter` has some free time, while **synchronous** methods will run in order always.

So this is the order in which the methods finish running:

> initstate -> build -> getMangaInfo

So by the time you build, getMangaInfo is not done.

I propose two solutions:

### 1. Use `setState` to tell flutter when to rebuild:

```
 Future<void> getMangaInfo() async {
    String  TempBaseurl = widget.mangalink.split(".com")[0] + ".com";
    String TempRoute = widget.mangalink.split(".com")[1];
    final webscraper = WebScraper(TempBaseurl);
    if (await webscraper.loadWebPage(TempRoute)){
     mangaDetail = webscraper.getElement("div.panel-story-info > div.story-info-right > table > tbody > tr > td.table-value", []);
     mangaDescList = webscraper.getElement("div.panel-story-info > div.panel-story-info-description", []);
   }

   setState(() {
     mangaGenre  = mangaDetail![3]['title'].toString().trim();
     mangaStatus = mangaDetail![2]['title'].toString().trim();
     mangaAuthor = mangaDetail![1]['title'].toString().trim();
     mangaDesc   = mangaDescList![0]['title'].toString().trim();
    });
  }
```

With the change above, the new order looks like this:

> initstate -> build -> getMangaInfo -> build.

### 2. Using a future builder:

This method is probably what I would do, but it might be confusing if you don't know what a `FutureBuilder` is:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screensize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getMangaInfo(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Constants.mygreen,
          title: Text(widget.mangaTitle),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: screensize.height,
          width: screensize.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                MangaInfo(
                  mangaImg: widget.mangaImg,
                  mangaStatus: mangaStatus??"Error" ,
                  mangaAuthor : mangaAuthor??"Error" ,
```

Comment: work proprely I use the second method you propose and It's all good ty